# nltk python library word tokenizatio error

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize a file.

```
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-81ae6f78b554> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 robert = open('Robert Frost.txt', 'r')
      3 robert_poem = robert.read()
----> 4 robert_poem_words = nltk.word_tokenization(robert_poem)

# AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'word_tokenization'`
```

The error is in the word_tokenization function.

Comment: Without seeing your code, specifically the word_tokenization function, how are we supposed to see what the problem is? Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
robert = open('Robert Frost.txt', 'r')
robert_poem = robert.read()
robert_poem_words = nltk.word_tokenize(robert_poem)
```

It should be `word_tokenize` not `word_tokenization`.